# Chinese character too large for enclosing character literal type

Tags: c++, char, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to assign the Chinese character 牛 as a char value in C++. On Xcode, I get the error:

> "Character too large for enclosing character literal type."

When I use an online IDE like JDoodle or Browxy, I get the error:

> "multi-character character constant."

It doesn't matter whether I use char, char16_t, char32_t or wchar_t, it won't work. I thought any Chinese character could at least fit into wchar_t, but this appears not to be the case. What can I do differently?

```
char letter = '牛';
char16_t character = '牛';
char32_t hanzi = '牛';
wchar_t word = '牛';
```

Comment: What encoding?  If you don't know the encoding you are working, it will be difficult to make any recommendations.  C++ certainly has deficiencies regarding encodings.  For example, Unicode UTF-8 a `char` type is not a _character_, rather it is a Unicode UTF-8 encoding unit, of which one-or-more of them are needed to express a single Unicode code point.  And it may take several Unicode code points to represent a single character.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of your [character literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) are standard `char`s.  To get a wider type, you need to include the proper prefix on the literal:

```
char letter = '牛';
char16_t character = u'牛';
char32_t hanzi = U'牛';
wchar_t word = L'牛';
```

Comment: Just note that there is no character encoding where `'牛'` (U+725B) will ever fit in a single `char`, so `char letter = '牛';` will never work. `char letter[] = "牛";` *may* work, depending on the encoding of the source file. Better would be `char letter[] = u8"牛";` for UTF-8 (or `char8_t` in C++20)